# Blackberry String to Date

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a String that contain a date, its format is "ddMMyyyy" (for example 21012012 is the current date (21/01/2012))

I want to convert it to a Date object.

Comment: A simple search for "java string date" on google gives 119000 hits. Stackoverflow give 103 hits. It's sometimes faster to search than asking the same question over and over...
Please take no offence, this is just my opinon.

Comment: Please take no offence too, but if i found something useful on google,i woudn't ask it on Stackoverflow, and not all the classes that are available in Java sdk are also available In Blackberry SDK, and thank you

Comment: @Mehdi so the SimpleDateFormat class is not available on BB's SDK ? Never worked with that SDK, but I'm pretty sure SimpleDateFormat is present in Java Micro Edition, so should be available. However I'll check it as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok, for BlackBerry the SimpleDateFormat is in package net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat and is fully compatible with Java Standard Edition's class http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: it is present, but the method parse is not

Comment: The parse method is not implemented in the BlackBerry API (which is based on Java-ME not Java-SE), a simple google search would have shown that as well. To be fair however, when asking questions about BlackBerry programming it is probably counter productive to include the Java tag.

Comment: My mistake, thought most java version handled date parsing the same way...

Comment: So, any idea to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for **only** for **"DDMMYYYY"** type;

Give like this:

> Date date=new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(dateChange("23012012")));
>           System.out.println("==============Date Object: "+date.getTime());

And the code for **dateChange()** method is:

```
public static String dateChange(String string)
{
    String str="";
    str=string.substring(4, string.length())+"-"+string.substring(2, 4)+"-"+string.substring(0, 2);
    return str;//Then I will get here like"2012-01-23";
}
```

You want Date object;

Then "date" object is in your hand;

Comment: I don't need thank you. Nothing is impossible. Any doubts on blackberry come on chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java  so many are there to clarify your and our doubts;

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and I never knew that a chat room exists, that would help a lot

Comment: click on this link:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: Ok, I agree with the answer but remember that this class only accepts some formats. You can read the formats list here: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html#parse(java.lang.String)